# How to Delete App Service -> Web App -> Log Files from C# OR Microsoft.Azure.Management

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Presently log in via Kudo / Azure CLI / FTP and manually delete.

We have an existing dev-ops codebase that uses `Microsoft.Azure.Management`.  Looking for any way to delete files, specifically `/LogFiles/*.log` where older than x using C# vaguely.

Seemingly could enumerate WebApps and get FTP credentials and use `FtpWebRequest` but would like to know if there is a more direct way.

Did not see any methods here -> [Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid there is not a direct way. However,you can call [Kudu Api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to delete the log files. Below is an example of powershell script:

```
$ResGroupName = ""
$WebAppName = ""
$LogFolder = ""
$DaysToKeepLogsAround=""

# Get publishing profile for web application

$WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $ResGroupName
[xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp

# Create Base64 authorization header

$username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($WebApp.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"

# delete log files

 $apiCommand = @{
        command = 'powershell.exe -command "Get-ChildItem -Path $LogFolder -Recurse -File | Where LastWriteTime  -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysToKeepLogsAround) | Remove-Item -Force"'
        dir=$LogFolder
    }

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiBaseUrl -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $base64AuthInfo";"If-Match"="*"} -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $apiCommand)
```

You can also refer to another example in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800853/how-to-clean-up-azure-web-app-logfiles-directory).

You can aslo create a **azure web job** and upload a powershell script to delete the old log files. Please check [here](https://swimburger.net/blog/azure/deleting-old-web-app-logs-using-azure-web-jobs-and-powershell) for detailed steps.